# Update Magento 2.3.0 to 2.4 Error in "Check Component Dependency"

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, composer-update

I'm trying to update Magento from 2.3.0 to 2.4 using the setup Wizard.

In the Readiness Check, I'm getting the following error:

**Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies.

Command "require" failed: Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/

In InitCommand.php line 697:

Package magento/product-community-edition at version 2.4.3 has a PHP requir
ement incompatible with your PHP version (7.2.34)

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [...]**

I can't find out how to fix this error.
I have tried changing the php from 7.2 to 7.3 or 7.4 but when I do, I get more errors in the Readiness Check.

Also, I tried using the composer self-update I get the folowing warning:

**The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.**

I'm using:
Magento v2.30
PHP v7.2
Composer v2.1.6

Any idea what the problem is and how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento isn't yet ready for Composer 2, so you need to downgrade composer to 1.x: `sudo composer self-update --1` and try running the update via the CLI again. Then you can use PHP 7.4 (or 7.3).

Comment: Hello @Brett, thank you for your help. I downgraded the composer to v1.10.22. What do you mean "try running the update via the CLI again'? Should I update the composer or update magento via CLI?

Comment: I mean on the command line, after downgrading to composer v1, run the update/upgrade process again.

Answer (score 0):

Install elasticsearch first

Take a backup of your both Magento files and database

Enable maintenance mode

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable

composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update

composer update
```

backup composer.json

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

remove magento product edition

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```

require product edition with 2.4.0

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

Update using composer

```
composer update

rm -rf generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Disable the maintenance mode

```
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: Hi, I tried it but din't work. When I ran the composer update command, I got these warnings/errors: 
"The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Comment: please downgrade composer version by running this command

composer self-update --1

Then try again!